# If mode is set to time then the DateTimePicker is not opening in android for react-native application

Tags: android, react-native, time, datetimepicker

I am working on a react-native application. I have DateTimePicker in my page with two separate functionalities of selecting date and other is for selecting time. DateTimePicker is working fine for both case in ios and also working fine for date mode and for mode="time" the DateTimePicker is not opening. I have used "react-native-modal-datetime-picker" library for DateTimePicker. Trying since so long but not getting solution. It would be great if I got solution.

Thank You.

Here is code for mode="time" which is not working.

```
  <DateTimePicker
   isVisible={this.state.isTimePickerVisible}
   onConfirm={this._handleTimePicked}
   onCancel={this._hideTimePicker}
   mode="time"
   date={ new Date()}
   />
```

In this if I remove mode then it will work and it choose mode="datetime" by default. And I want mode="time" to open.

Answer (score 1):

```
<TimePicker
    isVisible={this.state.isTimePickerVisible}
    onConfirm={this._handleTimePicked}
    onCancel={this._hideTimePicker}
    mode = {'time'}
    is24Hour = {true} />
```

Hope Your Problem will be Solved.

Comment: My problem is solved but with a different way. thanks for the suggestion.